# Entity Reference and Views

Tags: views, entities

Actually, I am looking for a solution of entity reference module, I don't know whether its possible or not. Please let me know if its possible.

Example:

Content Type : A
Content Type : B

Content type B  (a field) referencing Content Type A,

So, if I want to make a list of content of content type A, which is referencing in content type B, I can do it with views and entity relationship.

But I am looking for a solution where I want to make a list of content of Content type A, which is not referencing in content type B yet.

Is it possible, if yes then how?﻿

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really hard to answer with the information provided, but why not try adding a filter to your Filter Criteria in your View?  In that filter make sure that you set the Relationship Field to the correct Entity Reference Field, the set the Operator to "Is empty (null)".  That would filter Nodes which have no reference.